# Ошибка ImportError. Python Django

Tags: python, django

У меня вылезла ошибка при попытке запуска моего сайта.
Ошибка:

```
Error Can't find file 'settings.py' in the directory containing 'C\\Users\\....'
It appears you've customized things.
You'll have to run Django-admin.py, passing if your setting module.
(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow).
ImportError:
attempted relative import with know parent package.
```

Может кто-то дать совет как эту фигню исправить. Сразу говорю файл `'settings.py'` у меня есть. Заранее благодарю тех кто хоть как-то поможет.

Comment: Вам же написали  run Django-admin.py

Comment: Ничего не даёт если прописать

Comment: Посмотрите https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/